# Validity of the Following Calculation (Generators of $SO(3)$)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was reading the following page from the *Physics from Symmetry* by Jakop Schwichtenberg, I didn't quite understand the calculation.

Basically what he does is the following:

$J_1$ is one of the basis element for the generators of the group $SO(3)$ and is given by
\begin{align}
J_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
He is trying to show that, $e^{\theta J_{1}}$ will produce a well known rotation matrix in 3D as in the bottom of the page. So far so good. What I don't understand is that he defines the lower right $2\times 2$ matrix $j_1$ in $J_1$ and uses this  $2\times 2$ matrix to show that

\begin{align}
e^{\theta j_{1}} = \begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta) & cos (\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

But how does this helps us? How does he conclude the final result from it?

[image: taken from Physics from Symmetry by Jakop Schwichtenberg]

Comment: That looks like a very thorough explanation. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Then I am certainly missing something. Let me rephrase: how did he go from (3.68) to (3.69). Just because a submatrix of the matrix equals to (3.68) when exponantiated, can we say that the submatrix of the result (when the original matrix exponantiated) will also equal to (3.68). Basically, I don't understand how 3.68 helps us. Also, what does "using $e^0 = 1$ for the upper left component" means?

Comment: If we ignore the lower $2\times 2$ matrix, $I=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&*&*\\0&*&*}$ and $J_1^n=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&*&*\\0&*&*}$ for $n\ge1$ giving $\exp(\theta J_1)=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&*&*\\0&*&*}$.

Comment: Is this trivial? Because I'm still unable to see how this holds.